# Integral with an infinite sum

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Let:

$$\mathcal{S}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}-\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+k x)}{k^x}$$
I need help evaluating
$$\int_{0}^{1}\mathcal{S}(x) dx$$

Obviously the cosine term in the numerator simplifies to $\sin(kx)$, but I left it as it was presented to me and I can only assume a solution may come by treating $\sin(x)$ as $-\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{2})$. Numerial evaluation suggests:

$$\mathcal{S}(2)=i\frac12\big(\text{Li}_2(e^{-2i})-\text{Li}_2(e^{2i})\big)$$
$$\mathcal{S}(3)=i\frac12\big(\text{Li}_3(e^{-3i})-\text{Li}_3(e^{3i})\big)$$
Which leads me to believe:
$$\mathcal{S}(n)=i\frac12\big(\text{Li}_n(e^{-ni})-\text{Li}_n(e^{ni})\big)$$
But I can't prove it, and then the big problem is the integral, which I don't even know where to start on. I don't know whether it has a closed form, but I don't know if I can prove it's divergent either. How can I figure out the closed form for this integral?

Comment: You say $S(p)$, but there is no $p$ on the RHS of your equation. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AndresMejia I'm not exactly sure why I typed that - I meant x, sorry!

Comment: can you write $sin(kx)/k^x$ as real part of $e^{I k x}/k^x$, ie, the real part of $(e^{I k}/k)^x$ and integrate that term by term? Then you can maybe bound the sum by using Riemann integral sum trick to show at least convergence or not, and in the best case, upper and lower limits.

Comment: $$\mathcal{S}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(kx)}{k^x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{2ik^x} = \frac{i}{2}\left(\text{Li}_x(e^{-ix}) - \text{Li}_x(e^{ix})\right)$$

Comment: Ah, I meant to come back and answer this. @TreFox, do these comments sufficiently answer your question? To quote a maxim from a professor of mine: "there is only one trig identity: Euler's identity.